# How to find django timesince greater than an integer

Tags: python, django, time

In my templates I need to know if the 'timesince' a given variable is greater than another variable. If it is greater than for that row I add a class.

Can't figure out a way to compare these in the template and comparing them in the view seems equally complicated since I am not sure how I could loop over them, then pass that information reliably to the template to add a class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is 'timesince' a datetimeobject?

Comment: hm... don't think it is once it's in the template, but I will mess with it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with [`timesince`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince), you'll have to do this either with a custom tag or in your view.

I would recommend to do this in your view:

```
def someview(request):
   objs = Some.object.filter()
   ctx = {}
   ctx['objs'] = []  # hold your objects
   for i in objs:
      ctx['objs'].append((i,i.date_field < someother_obj.date_field))

   return render(request, 'template.html', ctx)
```

In your template:

```
{% for obj,flag in objs %}
    <tr><td {% if flag %}class="marked"{% endif %}>{{ obj }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to do it with a custom tag, create a template to show the row and then create an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) which has your comparison logic.

Comment: Burhan, thanks! This did the trick. I always wondered how to loop through a queryset and something like this without too much to disrupt the nice way they are returned to the template. I would be even cooler if you could annotate querysets in this way.